# Resizable login form in css

Tags: html, css

How can I make this login form resizable using CSS?

[image: here's the image]

Comment: Please show your code effort. Because we are here to help you not for to do your all code :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: A basic idea: set all sizes of the login panel and it's child elements as `em` (or `rem`), i.e. `width`, `height`, `font-size`, `margin`, `padding`, and so on. Then you can control the size of the whole login panel by simply changing its `font-size` css attribute (maybe using [viewport units](https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/), supported by all major browsers: http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units).

Answer (score -1):

In your case, a simple CSS will align the div to center.

set the main container div with the CSS:

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

Here is the working demo : [Codepen Link](http://codepen.io/jeffersonswartz/pen/NAELZa)